# in VS2010 Class Designer is it possible to specify namespace / folder for classes to go

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class-designer

in VS2010 Class Designer is it possible to specify namespace / folder for classes to go?

I created a design in a subdirectory however the classes seem to go into the root, and I can't see how to specific a folder or namespace?

Is the designer meant to be a one way or roundtrip tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this shows how to do it from a test-driven development perspective

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430051713/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/21/using-generate-from-usage-vstipedit0011.aspx)